# XML Parser only returning last element

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsxmlparser

So I'm building an app that requests an xml file and parses it. The following code puts the name in a label and the rest of the data is put into a text view. Now, I have included a condition in the if statement that counts how many times that loop has ran, only returning the first two elements. Or at least that's what I though it should do.

repCount is set to 0 initially.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURIqualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict { WeatherItem *weatherItem = [[WeatherItem alloc] init];

//Is a Location node
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Location"])
{

    weatherItem.name = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"name"];

    locationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", weatherItem.name];

    NSLog(@"weatherName---> %@", weatherItem.name);

}

//Is a Rep node
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Rep"] && repCount  <= 1)
{

    weatherItem.winddir = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"D"];
    weatherItem.visibility = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"V"];
    weatherItem.windspeed = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"S"];
    weatherItem.temperature = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"T"];
    weatherItem.precipprob = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"Pp"];
    weatherItem.weather = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"W"];


    NSLog(@"weatherItem---> %@", weatherItem.precipprob); //easiest value to keep track of

    resultsTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                            @"Wind Dir:%@\nVisibility:%@\nWind Speed:%@mph\nTemperature:%@C\nPrecip Prob.:%@%%\nWeather:%@\n",

                            weatherItem.winddir, weatherItem.visibility, weatherItem.windspeed,
                            weatherItem.temperature, weatherItem.precipprob, weatherItem.weather];

    repCount ++;



}

repCount = 0;}
```

The problem is that it only returns the very LAST element in the XML file rather than the first two. I would assume that it runs through the loop once (repCount is 0) then fires it to resultsTextView. Runs through it a second time (repCount is now 1) then adds it to what is fired to resultsTextView. It then stops as it would pass the check for repCount <= 1.

What have I missed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason is that you've got an assignment that clears out the `repCount` at the end of your method:

```
repCount = 0;
```

Setting `repCount` to zero needs to be done outside the method - either at initialization, or in the start document event handler. Currently, because `repCount` is reset after each element, the `&& repCount  <= 1` portion of your condition remains true for *every* element that you process, so the data for the last element overrides what's been there before.

Moving the `repCount = 0` assignment into the `parserDidStartDocument:` method of your NSXMLParserDelegate should fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew I had to reset it at some point to handle parsing the xml doc multiple times. It's been a long day... thanks again!

Comment: @user2152104 You are welcome! You may want to clear the `resultsTextView.text` at the start of the document, too, if you would like to append to it.